# Android O - confused of definiton of Implicit Intent and Explicit Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Basically, it's clear to distinguish implicit and explicit intent

> **Explicit Intents** have specified a component (via
>   setComponent(ComponentName) or setClass(Context, Class)), which
>   provides the exact class to be run. Often these will not include any
>   other information, simply being a way for an application to launch
>   various internal activities it has as the user interacts with the
>   application.
>
> **Implicit Intents** have not specified a component; instead, they must
>   include enough information for the system to determine which of the
>   available components is best to run for that intent.

But I'm confused by Google's introduced on https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

> For example, *ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED* is an implicit broadcast, since
>   it is sent to all registered listeners, letting them know that some
>   package on the device was replaced. However,
>   *ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED* is not an implicit broadcast, since it is
>   sent only to the app whose package was replaced, no matter how many
>   other apps have registered listeners for that broadcast.

Why ***ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED*** is not an implicit broadcast?

Comment: "it is sent only to the app whose package was replaced" - This means that the `Intent` is created to target the component registered for that broadcast, _and_ it carries the `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` action. Explicit `Intent`s can also have actions.

Comment: Yes, I know explicit *Intent* can also have actions, my doubt is why ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is considered as explicit.

Comment: Are you meaning this action is specified target package when sending by system?

Comment: An explicit `Intent` is created to target the component registered for it. Then, that action is added to the explicit `Intent`.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is a intent that is broadcasted ONLY to your application, since it is only triggered when YOUR application is replaced. This makes it a explicit Intent and as such is not subject to the limitation to android O.

However `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is sent to every app whenever a package gets replaced, thus it is not specific to your application. This makes is a implicit Intent and is therfore forbidden under android O's new background rules.

Answer (score 0):

> Why ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is not an implicit broadcast?

Because that's how Google wrote the code that sends `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcasts. They create an explicit `Intent`, identifying the specific receiver to receive the broadcast. They also attach the action string, in case the receiver happens to receive multiple broadcasts and needs to distinguish one from another. An explicit `Intent` is welcome to have an action string. The distinction between implicit and explicit `Intents` is whether the `Intent` identifies the component or not.